# Is it possible to see builtin function definition?

Tags: c++, built-in

This is pure curiosity, I'm using a cmath function, that is cos, whatever.
After looking at the cmath header, I see that kind of things:

```
 inline _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR float
  acos(float __x)
  { return __builtin_acosf(__x); }
```

And there is that "__ builtin__" and I don't find any source of that with google.
I'm interested in seeing the source code of how they implement a math function, I mean I guess they use taylor and stuff, but I wanted to see how they do it. Is it hidden for proprietary reasons or can it be found?

Comment: You'll need to dig into your compiler's source code for that.

Comment: GCC is open source, so it's not hidden, probably just not index by Google.

Answer (score 5):

GCC [`__builtin_` functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) are not actual functions, that is, they are not really declared and implemented anywhere as such, but instead they are detected by the compiler and mapped to some implementation. See [`builtins.h`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/builtins.h), [`builtins.c`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/builtins.c) and [`builtins.def`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/builtins.def). It is rather hard to track down where the actual implementations reside, but it seems that these mathematical functions are taken from the implementation of [libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) that you are using. For example, digging through [GLibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) source code, one can find at least a couple of implementations of `__ieee754_acosf` (which seems to be then aliased and wrapped by other function) one in C [`e_acosf.c`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_acosf.c) and one in x86 assembly [`a_acosf.S`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/i386/fpu/e_acosf.S) (backup links, since these are unofficial GitHub mirrors [`e_acosf.c`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_acosf.c) [`e_acosf.S`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/i386/fpu/e_acosf.S)). You could say that readability was not their first priority. You can find similar code in the [musl libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/) source tree: [acosf.c](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/math/acosf.c) in C an [acosf.s](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/math/i386/acos.s) in x86.

Comment: There was another answer (which I was going to upvote but now is gone) that pointed out that the implementation was originally from [Netlib](http://www.netlib.org/)'s [fdlibm](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/index.html), see [`e_acos.c`](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_acos.c), coming from Sun Microsystems apparently.