# How to show assembly output for builtin functions?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, godbolt

I tried to use godbolt online compiler to view the generated assembly for builtin functions. Example

```cpp
#include <cmath>

double br( double x ) {
    return __builtin_roundl(x);
}

double r( double x ) {
    return std::round( x );
}
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/7e76a6qv4.

But assembly output just showed as

```x86asm
br(double):
        jmp     round
r(double):
        jmp     round
```

I guess there has to be some compiler parameter to reveal the definition of builtin functions, but I could not find a suitable one.

What code gets generated in the end? Is there a way to get the call to `round` inlined?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48225114/4342498

Comment: NathanOliver's right, but also do note that godbolt filters output to only present user code by default. Check "Filter..." button below compiler selection.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Right, but only "Directives" seem to make a difference in output. Unfortunately, I did not learn something from that.

Answer (score 1):

> How to show assembly output for builtin functions?

You are showing the assembly output for a builting function in your code - it is `jmp     round`. The assembly function `__builtin_roundl` generated `jmp round` *in this case*, and it is correct.

There is no "assembly" for a builtin function. It only exists in the C compiler source code as a series of transformations on some abstraction over the language.

The code is here https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/fca6f6fddb22b8665e840f455a7d0318d4575227/gcc/convert.cc#L550 .

> I guess there has to be some compiler parameter to reveal the definition of builtin functions

There is none.

Comment: There is some code at `round` and as I understand the question it asks whether its possible to get compiler explorer to show it.

Comment: @Carsten No, `std::round()` is a library function, not a builtin. The question is about builtins.

Comment: @user207421, I left the call to `std::round()` in there just to show that the same builtin is called. The question is about what code gets generated in the end.

Comment: @KamilCuk, "a series of transformations on some abstraction over the language", well, yes, but in the end some code has to be generated.

Comment: Then, you are searching for the assembly code of the _library_ provided `roundl` function, in contrast to the builtin. The function is in c++ standard library. I wasn't  able to do that in godbolt, it is quite simple on Linux. I'll try to post when i get home. Are interested in assembly or the source code?

Comment: @KamilCuk You are probably right. I just compiled a call to `__builtin_roundl` into an executable and looked at the resulting code via `objdump -D a.out`. The call seems to result in a `jmp` to an addess commented with `<round@GLIBC_2.2.5>`. If you can provide the source code, please do.

Answer (score 0):

Check how much knowledge the compiler has, for example by calling `__builtin_roundl(3.7)` and checking that the result is just the constant `4.0`.

Now the implementation is just a single jmp. If the code is stored somewhere so you can use function pointers then this quite optimal. See what happens if you call `__builtin_roundl(x) + __builtin_roundl(x+1)` where inlining would be more likely.

Comment: I tried that, but just got to `call`s to `round`, no inlining.